# De facto session data storage

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session, cookies

I've noticed that there are quite a few technologyes for storing temporary session data(don't know how it is corectly called. For example:

Cookies

jQuery.data()

html5 storage

Php sessions

And probably plenty of others too.

What is the safest and least dependant on browser settings(like disabled cookies) way of transfering temporary user data(like shopping cart information or some variable/array) between pages on a website?

Cookies seems pretty simple but the user can disable those and I would like to find a more reliable way if there is one. User registration is and "logging in" is not an option at the moment.

What are some other technologyes/methods for this purpose?

Comment: What is the "correct" language to program a computer? This isn't a question. It's a koan.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase that. Which one of these technologyes is the most popular choice among profesional developers, which one is the safest, least reliable on the user browser settings(like disabled cookies)

Comment: Without cookies you really can't have sessions unless you inject garbage into each of your rendered URLs. Disabling cookies generally has the effect of disabling sessions as well.

Comment: So basically cookies, except from being insecure, are no worse then php sessions? Since both are disabled by disabling cookes

Comment: Usually sessions stored in cookies are encrypted so that the client can't decode or modify them, but the server can. The amount of data that can be stored in these cookies is also needs to be relatively limited as the cookie will be sent in with each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side storage.

Problem with jquery, cookies or html5 storage is that user can modify the data and that it can produce unexpected results depending on platform/browser/device combination user is running your code on.

Comment: Without a common store like memcached or a tuned database this doesn't work with multiple servers.

Comment: Tadman, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: If you store your session locally in a file, as is the default on some platforms, this file is not shared between servers. If you have a load-balancer in front of your application that doesn't have a session-affinity feature, your session data will randomly disappear or, worse, you could have two or more conflicting session states, an independent one for each server. This is why you need a shared storage facility.